# Unable to inject a specific classname to body tag when a specific WordPress page template loads

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a wordpress website in which there is a custom theme where I can create template parts for each webpage. I want to include/inject a specific class (ex: abc ) to the body tag in **header.php** when a specific page template (ex: abc.php) loads.

First I used the code bellow in **header.php** it did not work.

```
<body <?php if ( is_page_template( 'template-parts/page/abc.php' ) ) { body_class( 'abc' ); } else { body_class(); } ?>>
```

Then I added bellow code to **functions.php** but it is not working either.

```
add_filter( 'body_class','abc_class' );
function abc_class( $classes ) {

    if ( is_page_template( 'template-parts/page/abc.php' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'abc';
    }

    return $classes;

}
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong here. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add the following in **functions.php** so that it takes the slug  and inject that to the body class every time a specific page loads.

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
if ( is_page() ){
    $slug = get_queried_object()->post_name;
    return array_merge( $classes, array( $slug ) );
}
    return $classes;
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the is_page_template() function works for WP templates, I mean which have in the beginning of the file

```
/*
 * Template name: Your Super Template
 */
```

So, the function returns true is a page with this template is actually displaying. I will tell you more, you even do not have to add custom body classes because function body_class() adds specific unique classes for each page template :)

Second, the page templates can be in the theme directory itself or in 1-level subdirectory, so

```
<body <?php if ( is_page_template( 'abc.php' ) ) { body_class( 'abc' ); } else { body_class(); } ?>>
```

or

```
<body <?php if ( is_page_template( 'page-templates/abc.php' ) ) { body_class( 'abc' ); } else { body_class(); } ?>>
```

Your template in 2-level sub-directory, so it is not actually a Page Template, it is a template part.

So, in two words, the function is_page_template() is for Page Templates but not for template parts